# Is there a shorthand for this in ES6/ES7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm having a bit of a brainfart. Is there a shorthand for this in ES6/ES7?

`res.locals.hello = hello`

I've tried a few different combinations but can't get anything to stick.

Comment: What kind of shorthand would you be looking for? I can't think of any reasonable way this could be simplified.

Comment: You may be thinking of `{ hello }` which transpiles to `{ hello: hello }`. This is one of many enhancements made to object literals in ES6.

Comment: Well if I wanted to destructure this the other way around, I Could use `let { hello } = res.locals` . I was hoping there was a similar shorthand for going the other direction.

Comment: looks pretty short to me.  you can make it shorter by minifying it.  r.l.h=h

Comment: I hope we don't get questions like this for every possible thing you could do in JavaScript.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. I thought there was a solution but surprisingly couldn't find it while tinkering. I posted the question to SO and someone helped me with a solution. Is there something inherently wrong with that in your view?

Comment: In more complicated scenarios (i.e. when you want to assign several fields) you may do it with `Object.assing`, e.g. `Object.assing(res.locals, { hello }) `.

Comment: Thanks for the post Leonid but you've got a little typo, should be `Object.assign(res.locals, { hello })` (haven't tested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a shorter way to arbitrarily attach a new key to an object, and automatically assign a reference with the same name. However, during the construction of your `locals` object, you can simply provide the handler:

```js
let res = {
    locals: { hello }
};
```

This is effectively the same as:

```js
let res = {
    locals: {
        hello: hello
    }
};
```

This enhancement was added in ES6, and is supported by all transpilers to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was going to write up the same thing myself. What I am going to use is `res.locals = { hello }`

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming `res` already exists, using `res.locals = { hello }` works just fine.

Comment: If `res.locals` has other properties, `res.locals = {hello}` will blow them away.

Comment: If I needed to I could use Object#assign but that's not an issue I'm facing at the moment.

Comment: In fact, this works better if `res.locals` does NOT exist.